# Handling exception on client side with gwtp + REST

Tags: java, rest, gwt, exception, gwtp

I'm using gwtp with REST services, using ResourceDelegate to share my interface between client and server. For the moment everything works fine.

Now I want to add exception-handling on the client side and after reading the official documentation, the carstore sample, multiple posts on SO, I'm still wondering what is done by the framework and what is left to me.

So, for the moment, on the server side I use Spring and REST Easy and my resource looks like this :
Interface :

```
package ***.shared.rest;

@Path("books")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)    
public interface BookResources {

    @GET
    BookDTO getBook(@PathParam("id") Integer bookId) throws BookKeyDecodingException;
}
```

Implementation :

```
package ***.server.rest;

@Component
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public class BookResourcesImpl implements BookResources {

    @Autowired
    private BookService bookService;

    @Autowired
    private DtoFactory dtoFactory;

    @Override
    public BookDTO getBook(String bookKey) throws BookKeyDecodingException {
        BookDTO bookDTO = BookKeyUtils.decode(supplementKey);
        BookModel bookModel = dtoFactory.convertSupplementSuggestionDTO(suggestionDTO);                 
        return bookService.getBook(bookDTO.getId());            
    }
}
```

The `BookKeyDecodingException` is in the ***.shared.exception package and is serializable.

On the client side, my presenter will use my resourceDelegate :

```
package ***.client.application.book;

public class BookPresenter {
    ...

    private void fetch() {
        clearSlot(SLOT_BOOK);
        try {
            bookDelegate.withCallback(new AsyncCallback<BookDTO>() {

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    **???**
                }

                @Override
                public void onSuccess(BookDTO result) {

                    for (CahierDTO cahier : result.getPages()) {
                        ...
                    }

                }
            }).getBook(bookKey);
        } catch (BookKeyDecodingException e) {
            **???**
        }
    }
}
```

And I'm still wondering :

- Will it falls to the catch clause ?
- To the onFailure() methods ?
- None of those ?
- Am I suppose to manage the error status and some
  exception serialization on the server side or is this all magic ?

Comment: Addendum : with this configuration, the exception fall to the onFailure() method with a generic exception, not a BookKeyDecodingException one...

Answer (score 0):

So now I got a solution but I'm not sure it's the best one, but I think it might help someone ...

I didn't find any *big* magic (but many *small* ones) :

1. I handle any exception on the server side and I serialize it
2. On the client side, when I fall in onFailure(), I don't process the caught parameter but the REST response and I deserialize it
3. I fire an ErrorEvent containing the exception
4. I handle it with an ErrorPresenter revealing its own place after setting the exception as its context (using the @ProxyEvent annotation).
5. I create the view content by using a visitor pattern, allowing to visit the exception hierarchy to retrieve the error title, message and details

All of this is quite complex but now I have a generic system working with any king of known and shared exception between server and client and I don' rely on error codes to get the content to display, only on the exception hierarchy.

**Details**

All my exceptions are in the shared package, serializable and extend BookException.

**1. Handling exception server side.**

I use RestEasy, so I can implement and ExceptionMapper :

```
package ***.server.rest;

@Provider
@Component
public class BookExceptionHandler implements ExceptionMapper<BookException> {

    @Override
    public Response toResponse(BookException exception) {
        return Response.serverError().tag(exception.getClass().getName()).entity(exception).build();
    }
}
```

The exception class name will be found in a dedicated **tag** so I will be able to deserialize it...

**2. Handling exception client side. and 3. Fire an ErrorEvent**

I use RestyGWT, so I define a generic MethodCallback :

```
package ***.client.application.error;

public abstract class ErrorEventDistpacherMethodCallback<DTO> implements MethodCallback<DTO> {

    @Inject
    static ResourceFailureErrourEventDispatcher dispatcher;

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Method method, Throwable caught) {
        dispatcher.onFailure(method, caught);
    }
}
```

The Method object gives me access to the header and body of the REST Response. The hard part in on the dispatcher : I want it to deserialize the exception and to fire the event.
Good news : RestyGWT comes with JsonEncoderDecoder interface that I can use. So I have to extends it for each of my exceptions and to link it with the corresponding type found in the dedicated **tag**.

```
package **.client.exceptions.technical.codecs;

public interface BookKeyDecodingExceptionCodec extends ExceptionCodec<BookKeyDecodingException>, JsonEncoderDecoder<BookKeyDecodingException> {
}
```

Why do I need a generic `ExceptionCodec<BookKeyDecodingException>` ? Because I want to put them in a  `Map<String, ExceptionCodec<?>>` .

```
public class ResourceFailureErrorEventDispatcher implements HasHandlers {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(ErreurEventDistpacherMethodCallback.class.getSimpleName());
    private static final String EXCEPTION_CLASS_PARAM_NAME = "ETag";

    private Map<String, ExceptionCodec<?>> mapExceptionCodecByClassName = new HashMap<String, ExceptionCodec<?>>();

    private EventBus eventBus;

    ...

    public BookException buildException(Method method, Throwable caught) {
        String className = method.getResponse().getHeader(EXCEPTION_CLASS_PARAM_NAME);
        String json = method.getResponse().getText();

        BookException result = null;

        if (className == null) {
            result = new UnexpectedResourceException((Exception) caught);       
            LOGGER.severe("Unexpected technical exception :" + result.getMessage());
        } else if (mapExceptionCodecByClassName.containsKey(className)) {
            result = mapExceptionCodecByClassName.get(className).decode(json);
        } else {
            result = new MissingExceptionCodecException(className);
        }

        return result;
    }

    public void onFailure(Method method, Throwable caught) {
        if (caught instanceof RequestTimeoutException) {
            ErrorEvent.fire(this, new NetworkException());
        } else {
            ErrorEvent.fire(this, buildException(method, caught));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void fireEvent(GwtEvent<?> event) {
        eventBus.fireEventFromSource(event, this);
    }
}
```

I could manage the codecs by annotation / generator but for the moment, I'm happy with that.
If you have any remark or advice on this solution, don't hesitate to comment / answer !

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with GWTP and [Restlet](https://restlet.com/open-source/) and created a custom solution (ClientProxyGenerator) for this;

[Receive custom exceptions from Restlet Framework in GWT client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45505340/receive-custom-exceptions-from-restlet-framework-in-gwt-client)